# Is this patent legal?

Tags: international, patent-infringment

In reference to the patent: [EP3247374A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP3247374A1)

Is this patent an infringement in progress?
This patent is currently being discussed (2018-4-24) as a hot topic in China Taiwan's media. 
The patent was originally owned by Dong Hua University in Taiwan and without documentation of approval or potentially without University's knowledge this patent in Taiwan maybe taken by Wu Maokun and applied as Patent in the USA. 
Is this considered an infringement? 
see youtube video:  www.youtube.com/watch?UsECC881dIY   (Part2 of video)
starting from time 00:00 till 10:40 (~10 minutes) is talking about this is maybe illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat ambiguous. I'll attempt to answer it as well as I can. The linked document is an application, not a patent. It may or may not ever become a patent and even if it does, it's claims may be narrowed over what is in the application. If there is published prior art before the application's priority date of January 21, 2015 then that can be cause for the application being rejected. As for the Youtube video, talking about a patent or published application is not an infringement. A patent protects what is claimed. In this case, the application is attempting to patent a medication. If it gets granted, then the  medication as described in the claims is protected. Patent protection is limited to the country they are granted in.